# How to iterate through columns in a row to find the first that meets some criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I need to iterate through columns in a row of a dataframe to find the first cell (in this given row) that is fully capitalized. I need to repeat this for all rows in the dataframe, finally outputting a dataframe with one column and each row with the corresponding first capitalized string.

As an example - this could be the input dataframe:

```
+-----+--------+--------+--------+------+
|  0  |   1    |   2    |   3    |  4   |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+------+
| a   | Amount | SEQ    | LTOTAL | None |
| BBc | LCALC  | None   | None   | None |
| c   | LCALC  | None   | None   | None |
| Dea | RYR    | LTOTAL | None   | None |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

And I would need the output to be the following, in a separate dataframe:

```
+-------+
| SEQ   |
| LCALC |
| LCALC |
| RYR   |
+-------+
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Itay tried a for loop using enumerate(df.columns) but couldn't get anywhere with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If need check all columns test values by `isupper` and replace non matched values to `NaN`s, so possible back filling missing values and seelct first column by `iloc`:

```
df = df.where(df.applymap(lambda x: x.isupper())).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].to_frame('col')
print (df)
     col
0    SEQ
1  LCALC
2  LCALC
3    RYR
```

EDIT:

Create `df1` with columns by position of matched values, so first column are first upper values, ...:

```
#reshape by stack, None and NaNs columns are removed, 
#remove second level of MultiIndex
s = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
#filter only upper values, convert to DataFrame
df1  = s[s.str.isupper()].rename_axis('idx').reset_index(name='val')
#create counter column for count first, second... columns
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('idx').cumcount()
#reshape by pivot and if necessary add non upper rows
df1 = df1.pivot('idx','g','val').reindex(df.index)
print (df1)
g      0       1
0    SEQ  LTOTAL
1  LCALC     NaN
2  LCALC     NaN
3    RYR  LTOTAL

first = df1[0].to_frame('col')
second = df1[1].to_frame('col')
print (first)
    col
0    SEQ
1  LCALC
2  LCALC
3    RYR

print (second)
      col
0  LTOTAL
1     NaN
2     NaN
3  LTOTAL
```

Comment: If there are rows with no capitalization/there are None's present instead - how to I modify the code to not return the following error: AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isupper'"). I'd like it to return a None value in place of where the capitalized string should be in the list. I've tried try and except but not exactly sure what to put under the except statement.

Comment: @user1611612 then use `df = df.where(df. fillna('not').applymap(lambda x: x.isupper())).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].to_frame('col')
print (df)`

Comment: Thanks - one final question, say I wanted to return the second value in caps along the row in a new dataframe, how would I modify this now.

Comment: @user1611612 - Do you need only first, second ot also third, fourth.. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_first_upper(row):
    for val in row:
        if val and val.isupper():
            return val
df1.apply(get_first_upper)
```

Comment: If there are rows with no capitalization/there are None's present instead - how to I modify the code to not return the following error: AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isupper'"). I'd like it to return a None value in place of where the capitalized string should be in the list. I've tried the following: 
`def get_first_upper(row): for val in row: if val.isupper(): return val if AttributeError: return  None df3=df2.apply(get_first_upper)`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate rows with

```py
column = list()

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for item in row:
        if item.isupper():
            column.append(item)
            break
    else:
        column.append(numpy.nan)

new_df = pandas.DataFrame(column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to iterate through the row and break at first instance of an all caps cell in the row

```
import pandas as pd
l=[]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    for i in row:
            if(i.isuppercase()):
                    l.append(i)
                    break
new_df = pandas.DataFrame(l)
```